# Yarn re-load or pass new config after 'preinstall'

Tags: npm, aws-cli, yarnpkg, package.json, aws-codeartifact

I'm trying to utilize a private repo using [AWS CodeArtifact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/npm-yarn.html). The instructions there mention executing a `aws-cli` npm login command. This login command grabs a token from AWS and places it in the users `.npmrc`.

I had tried to put this login function in a `preinstall` script in the projects `package.json` but the problem is that `.npmrc` is only modified in this step and not reloaded when proceeding to the `yarn install` task.

Is there any way to load this token into `yarn` while keeping the login / install process seamless?

Comment: related: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8821

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the other answer, but a bit simpler, I added this as my preinstall script

Where the code to login is in the preinstall.js file. Could use the AWS CLI command too.

```
"preinstall": "node preinstall.js && yarn install --ignore-scripts && yarn postinstall && exit 0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with gcloud. I managed to hack it by adding a yarn preinstall hook to `package.json`

```
    "preinstall": "yarn install --ignore-scripts; kill -9 $(ps | grep 'yarn.js install' | awk 'NR==1' | awk '{print $1}')"
```

It's always not necessary to also kill the yarn install either. Your "second" install would just get a cache hit and it will be fast.

You can also add `/bin/bash -c ' if [[ -n ${ENV_VARIABLE:-} ]]; then blabla; fi'` to make the command only run in the environment you want.